# Using Entity Framework and where queries without creating lots of queries (avoiding N+1)

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, navigation-properties, select-n-plus-1

I've been using a design pattern that after using the Entity Framework Profiler seems like it might be quite foolish.

I've been extended my entity classes to have properties that are filtered views of a collection associated with that entity. Like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Member> ActiveMembers
{
    get
    {
        return Members.Where(t => t.LeftDate == null);
    }
}
```

As I'm mainly interested in members who have not left the club this property was very useful and seemed to make sense.

However from running the EF Profiler I now know that this often leads to N+1 problems. If I loop through the members and also want to show their address then each request for an address results in an extra db query.

I know from this [question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998218) that I could modify my property to:

```
return Members.CreateSourceQuery().Include("Address")
              .Where(t => t.LeftClubDate == null);
```

This would get rid of the N+1 problem in this case, but I don't always want the address information and I might want to follow another navigation property from Member.

Ideally I want to be able to keep the flexibility of my filtered properties like ActiveMembers and be able to decide afterwards what properties to include in the query. Like this:

```
var membersToDisplay = ActiveMembers.Include("Address").ToList();
```

Is this possible, or do I need to rething my filtered properties idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible to call `Include` on `IEnumerable`. `Include` is feature of `ObjectQuery` / `DbQuery`. It is possible to call `Include` on `IQueryable` (with EFv4.1 or custom extension) but it still internally cast passed query to `ObjectQuery` or `DbQuery` and throws exception if cast cannot be done. You must redesign your application.

> I don't always want the address
>   information and I might want to follow
>   another navigation property from
>   Member.

You have to fill data based on your current needs or live with N+1 problem. For example you can use separate linq query:

```
var clubId = ActiveClub.Id;
var members = (from member in context.Members.Include("Address")
               where member.LeftDate == null and member.ClubId == clubId
               select member).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It looks like I need to redesign a few things.