# Entity Framework LoadProperty with multiple references

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

With entity framework you can do something like this to load objects for multiple references with a query.

```
var Customer = context.Customers.Include(x=>x.Orders.Select(y=>y.Items));
```

It doesn't seem like I can do the same thing with the LoadProperty method. When I already have an object and I need to load some reference data I use LoadProperty.

```
context.LoadProperty(Customer, x=>x.Orders);
```

That works. But this throws an error..

```
context.LoadProperty(Customer, x=>x.Orders.Select(y=>y.Items));
```

And so does this...

```
context.LoadProperty(Customer.Orders, x=>x.Items);
```

This is the exception for both cases...

> The selector expression for
>   LoadProperty must be a MemberAccess
>   for the property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No `LoadProperty` doesn't allow that. You can try to use approach described in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998218/using-entity-framework-navigation-properties-without-creating-lots-of-queries-av/5998536#5998536).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and ended up looping through the entities and loading them one by one:

```
EFContext.LoadProperty(primingRunSelector, f => f.PrimingRun);
EFContext.LoadProperty(primingRunSelector.PrimingRun, f => f.PrimingFillbagAssignedTos);
foreach (var primingFillbagAssignedTo in primingRunSelector.PrimingRun.PrimingFillbagAssignedTos) EFContext.LoadProperty(primingFillbagAssignedTo, f => f.PrimingFillbag);
```